# Trying to extract ONLY last name using regex from list

Tags: python, regex, string, list

I'm having some problem extracting the last name from a list.

```
list = ['Cristiano Ronaldo', 'L. Messi', 'M. Neuer', 'L. Suarez', 'De Gea', 'Z. Ibrahimovic', 'G. Bale', 'J. Boateng', 'R. Lewandowski']

for item in list:
    print(item)
    print(re.findall(r'(\s(.*))', item))
```

But the output is as such:

```
Cristiano Ronaldo
[(' Ronaldo', 'Ronaldo')]
L. Messi
[(' Messi', 'Messi')]
M. Neuer
[(' Neuer', 'Neuer')]
L. Suarez
[(' Suarez', 'Suarez')]
De Gea
[(' Gea', 'Gea')]
Z. Ibrahimovic
[(' Ibrahimovic', 'Ibrahimovic')]
G. Bale
[(' Bale', 'Bale')]
J. Boateng
[(' Boateng', 'Boateng')]
R. Lewandowski
[(' Lewandowski', 'Lewandowski')]
```

I am curious as to why the last names were returned twice; I only want to get back the last names once.

Can any of you kind folks help? Thank you!

Comment: You have 2 nested groups, one that includes the space and one that doesn't. Your regex wouldn't handle the case where middle names were included? Why not split the string and return the last element?

Comment: You are capturing two groups. I would do it like [this](https://regex101.com/r/eAE6IF/1). `\w+$`

Answer (score 3):

Use `str.split()` with negative indexing

**Ex:**

```
lst = ['Cristiano Ronaldo', 'L. Messi', 'M. Neuer', 'L. Suarez', 'De Gea', 'Z. Ibrahimovic', 'G. Bale', 'J. Boateng', 'R. Lewandowski']

for item in lst:
    print(item)
    print(item.split()[-1])
```

**Output:**

```
Ronaldo
Messi
Neuer
Suarez
Gea
Ibrahimovic
Bale
Boateng
Lewandowski
```

Answer (score 3):

You create 2 group with the two pairs of brackets. Remove the outer one and you will get only the last name:

```
list = ['Cristiano Ronaldo', 'L. Messi', 'M. Neuer', 'L. Suarez', 'De Gea', 'Z. Ibrahimovic', 'G. Bale', 'J. Boateng', 'R. Lewandowski'] 
for item in list: 
    print(item) 
    print(re.findall(r'\s(.*)', item))
```

Answer (score 1):

`\S` matches any character that is not a space.

```
list = ['Cristiano Ronaldo', 'L. Messi', 'M. Neuer', 'L. Suarez', 'De Gea', 'Z. Ibrahimovic', 'G. Bale', 'J. Boateng', 'R. Lewandowski']

for item in list:
    print(item)
    print(re.findall(r'\S+$', item)) # match 1 or more non space before end of string
```

**Output:**

```
Cristiano Ronaldo
['Ronaldo']
L. Messi
['Messi']
M. Neuer
['Neuer']
L. Suarez
['Suarez']
De Gea
['Gea']
Z. Ibrahimovic
['Ibrahimovic']
G. Bale
['Bale']
J. Boateng
['Boateng']
R. Lewandowski
['Lewandowski']
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this out https://regex101.com/r/CGrruO/1

You can see that your regex returns 2 matches.
You added another set of () so you got two matches, one with space and one without.

Changing to `\s(.*)` should work